# Node secure Websocket with IIS (Windows)

Tags: node.js, websocket, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

So I have created an application that uses a websocket in node.

In my server.js I use:

```
import http from "http";
import WebSocket from "websocket";

[...]
var httpServer = http.createServer(this.handleRequest);
httpServer.listen(port, function () {
  console.log("Listening on port " + port);
});
var server = new WebSocket.server({httpServer: http_server});
[...]
```

This works, and creates a socket server on the same url.

Now, I'm trying to get this on a Windows server with IIS.
I start the application with "node server.js" and it is running on port 5003.
In IIS I use a rewrite rule to forward all incomming requests to the node server. Works perfect.

Now the problem. When I install an certificate with LetsEncrypt (Win-AMCE) the website is secure, but it won't connect to the websocket as the websocket is not secure.

According to some finds on the internet I need to use npm `https`

```
import http from "https";
import WebSocket from "websocket";
import fs from "fs";

[...]

const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync("my-site-key.pem"),
  cert: fs.readFileSync("chain.pem")
};

var httpsServer = https.createServer(options,this.handleRequest);
httpsServer.listen(port, function () {
  console.log("Listening on port " + port);
});
var server = new WebSocket.server({httpsServer: http_server});
[...]
```

The problem is, how do I get some valid certificate files. I cannot sign them self because another error will popup I guess. I cannot find the files Letsencrypt created.

So.... how do I create a secure websocket??

Comment: If you're sharing the same port as the external facing server then you can also share the TLS/certificate. I'm not exactly sure of how IIS works in this regard but if you're using a reverse proxy then it's as simple as ensuring the forwarding rules exist for port 443 (with the certificate). Then simply use wss as the protocol instead of ws.